# Как не дожидаться загрузки yandex maps?

Tags: javascript

есть такой скрипт который позволяет добавить прелоадер

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  var preloader = $('.preloader')
  $(preloader).delay(300).fadeOut('slow');
  $('section.main').addClass('loader')
  AOS.init();
});
```

Однако данный prealoder ожидает и загрузки yandex maps которая в самом конце страницы и могла бы загрузиться по ходу работы. Можно ли как то сделать что бы загрузка страницы считалось без полной загрузки yandex maps

Comment: А как у вас подключаются яндекс карты? Если можно напишите этот код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновился до 5.0.2 но в нем такая же ошибка. 
Что бы исправить данный фикс надо добавить в файле svg в начале кода след. текст

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```